# What can I do to solve over-fitting problem in following code?

Tags: python, machine-learning

> I'm trying to build a Handwritten word recognition using **IAM Dataset**
>   and while training I'm facing **over fitting** problem. Would you please
>   help me figure out what mistake I have made in code below.

I have tried all the solution that I can find to resolve the problem but still the same overfitting problem persists.

```
import os
import fnmatch
import cv2
import numpy as np
import string
import time
import random
from keras import regularizers, optimizers
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Reshape, BatchNormalization, Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Lambda, Bidirectional, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.activations import relu, sigmoid, softmax
import keras.backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,ReduceLROnPlateau
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



imgSize = (128,32)

def preprocess(img, imgSize, dataAugmentation=False):

    "put img into target img of size imgSize, transpose for TF and normalize gray-values"

    # there are damaged files in IAM dataset - just use black image instead
    if img is None:
        img = np.zeros([imgSize[1], imgSize[0]])

    # increase dataset size by applying random stretches to the images
    if dataAugmentation:
        stretch = (random.random() - 0.5) # -0.5 .. +0.5
        wStretched = max(int(img.shape[1] * (1 + stretch)), 1) # random width, but at least 1
        img = cv2.resize(img, (wStretched, img.shape[0])) # stretch horizontally by factor 0.5 .. 1.5
        img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
        # print('Data Augmented')

    # create target image and copy sample image into it
    (wt, ht) = imgSize
    (h, w) = img.shape
    fx = w / wt
    fy = h / ht
    f = max(fx, fy)
    newSize = (max(min(wt, int(w / f)), 1), max(min(ht, int(h / f)), 1)) # scale according to f (result at least 1 and at most wt or ht)
    img = cv2.resize(img, newSize)
    target = np.ones([ht, wt]) * 255
    target[0:newSize[1], 0:newSize[0]] = img

    # transpose for TF
    img = cv2.transpose(target)

    # normalize
    (m, s) = cv2.meanStdDev(img)
    m = m[0][0]
    s = s[0][0]
    img = img - m
    img = img / s if s>0 else img
    img = np.expand_dims(img , axis = 2) 

    return img

def truncateLabel(text, maxTextLen):  # A,32

    cost = 0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if i != 0 and text[i] == text[i-1]:
            cost += 2
        else:
            cost += 1
        if cost > maxTextLen:
            return text[:i]  # returns words with repeated chars
    return text

path = 'iam_dataset_words/'
maxTextLen = 32
samples = []
bad_samples = []
fileName = ''
dataAugmentation = False
chars = set()
f=open(path+ 'words.txt', "r")
cou = 0
bad_samples = []
bad_samples_reference = ['a01-117-05-02.png',
                                 'r06-022-03-05.png']
for line in f:
    cou+=1
    # ignore comment line
    if not line or line[0]=='#':
        continue

    lineSplit = line.strip().split(' ')
    assert len(lineSplit) >= 9

    fileNameSplit = lineSplit[0].split('-') #a01-000u-00-00 splits
    #../data/words/a01/a01-000u/a01-000u-00-00.png
    fileName = path + 'words/' \
                       + fileNameSplit[0] + '/' \
                       + fileNameSplit[0] + '-' \
                       + fileNameSplit[1] \
                       + '/' + lineSplit[0] + '.png'

    # GT text are columns starting at 9
    gtText = truncateLabel(' '.join(lineSplit[8:]), maxTextLen) #A,32
    #chars = chars.union(gtText) #unique chars only
    chars = chars.union(set(list(gtText)))

    # check if image is not empty
    if not os.path.getsize(fileName):
        bad_samples.append(lineSplit[0] + '.png')
        continue

    # put sample into list
    #'A','../data/words/a01/a01-000u/a01-000u-00-00.png'
    samples.append([gtText, fileName])

print(cou) 
print(len(samples))
print(samples[:2])

if set(bad_samples) != set(bad_samples_reference):
    print("Warning, damaged images found:", bad_samples)
    print("Damaged images expected:", bad_samples_reference)

trainSamples = []
validationSamples = []
testSamples = []
valid_testSamples = []
# split into training and validation set: 90% - 10%
# dataAugmentation = True
random.shuffle(samples)
splitIdx = int(0.75 * len(samples))
train_samples = samples[:splitIdx]
valid_testSamples = samples[splitIdx:]
print('vv:', len(valid_testSamples))
validationSamples = valid_testSamples[:15000]
testSamples = valid_testSamples[15000:]
print('valid: ',len(validationSamples))
print('test: ',len(testSamples))
print('train_before: ',len(train_samples))

# # start with train set

trainSamples = train_samples[:25000] #tran data 25000
print('train_ after: ',len(trainSamples))
# # list of all unique chars in dataset
charList = sorted(list(chars))
char_list = str().join(charList)
# print('test samples: ',testSamples)
print('char list : ',char_list)

# # save characters of model for inference mode
# open(FilePaths.fnCharList, 'w').write(str().join(charList))
# # save words contained in dataset into file
# open(FilePaths.fnCorpus, 'w').write(str(' ').join(loader.trainWords + validationWords))

def encode_to_labels(txt):
    # encoding each output word into digits
    chars = []
    for index, char in enumerate(txt):
        try:
            chars.append(char_list.index(char))
        except:
            print(char)

    return  chars

print(trainSamples[:2])

# lists for training dataset
train_img = []
train_txt = []
train_input_length = []
train_label_length = []
train_orig_txt = []
max_label_len = 0
b = 0

for words, imgPath in trainSamples:
  img = preprocess(cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), imgSize, dataAugmentation = True)

  # compute maximum length of the text
  if len(words) > max_label_len:
    max_label_len = len(words)

  train_orig_txt.append(words)   
  train_label_length.append(len(words))
  train_input_length.append(31)
  train_img.append(img)
  train_txt.append(encode_to_labels(words)) 
  b+=1

# print(train_img[1])

print(len(train_txt))
train_txt[:5]

a = 0
#lists for validation dataset
valid_img = []
valid_txt = []
valid_input_length = []
valid_label_length = []
valid_orig_txt = []

for words, imgPath in validationSamples:
  img = preprocess(cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), imgSize, dataAugmentation = False)

  valid_orig_txt.append(words)   
  valid_label_length.append(len(words))
  valid_input_length.append(31)
  valid_img.append(img)
  valid_txt.append(encode_to_labels(words))
  a+=1

print(len(valid_txt))
valid_txt[:5]

# lists for training dataset
test_img = []
test_txt = []
test_input_length = []
test_label_length = []
test_orig_txt = []
c = 0

for words, imgPath in testSamples:
  img = preprocess(cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), imgSize, dataAugmentation = False)

  test_orig_txt.append(words)
  test_label_length.append(len(words))
  test_input_length.append(31)
  test_img.append(img)
  test_txt.append(encode_to_labels(words)) 
  c+=1
  # print(c)

print(test_img[0].shape)
print('Train: {}\nValid: {}\nTest: {}'.format(b,a,c))

print(max_label_len)
# pad each output label to maximum text length
train_padded_txt = pad_sequences(train_txt, maxlen=max_label_len, padding='post', value = len(char_list))
valid_padded_txt = pad_sequences(valid_txt, maxlen=max_label_len, padding='post', value = len(char_list))
test_padded_txt = pad_sequences(test_txt, maxlen=max_label_len, padding='post', value = len(char_list))

print(len(train_padded_txt))
print(len(test_padded_txt))
print(valid_padded_txt[1]) 
# input with shape of height=32 and width=128 
inputs = Input(shape=(128,32,1))
print(inputs.shape)
# convolution layer with kernel size (3,3)
conv_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(inputs)
batch_norm_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv_1)
# poolig layer with kernel size (2,2)
pool_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=2, padding='valid')(batch_norm_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
batch_norm_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv_2) 

pool_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=2, padding='valid')(batch_norm_2)
conv_3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_2)
batch_norm_3 = BatchNormalization()(conv_3)

conv_4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(batch_norm_3)
batch_norm_4 = BatchNormalization()(conv_4) 
# poolig layer with kernel size (1,2)
pool_4 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(1,2))(batch_norm_4)
conv_5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
# Batch normalization layer
batch_norm_5 = BatchNormalization()(conv_5)

conv_6 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(batch_norm_5)

batch_norm_6 = BatchNormalization()(conv_6)

pool_6 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(1,2))(batch_norm_6)
conv_7 = Conv2D(256, (2,2), activation = 'relu')(pool_6)
batch_norm_7 = BatchNormalization()(conv_7) 
# print(conv_7.shape)
# map-to-sequence-- dropping 1 dimension
squeezed = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, 2))(batch_norm_7)
# print('squeezed',squeezed.shape)
# bidirectional LSTM layers with units=128
blstm_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.3))(squeezed)
blstm_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.3))(blstm_1)
outputs = Dense(len(char_list)+1, activation = 'softmax')(blstm_2)

# model to be used at test time
word_model = Model(inputs, outputs)





adam = optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.01, decay = 1e-5)
model.compile(loss= {'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer = adam, metrics = ['accuracy'])

filepath="best_model.hdf5"
checkpoint1 = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,
                              mode='auto',factor=0.2,patience=4, min_lr=0.0001)
checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint1, checkpoint2]

train_img = np.array(train_img)
train_input_length = np.array(train_input_length)
train_label_length = np.array(train_label_length)

valid_img = np.array(valid_img)
valid_input_length = np.array(valid_input_length)
valid_label_length = np.array(valid_label_length)

test_img = np.array(test_img)
test_input_length = np.array(test_input_length)
test_label_length = np.array(test_label_length)

test_img.shape

batch_size = 50
epochs = 30
train_history = model.fit(x=[train_img, train_padded_txt, train_input_length, train_label_length], 
          y=np.zeros(len(train_img)), batch_size=batch_size, epochs = epochs, 
          validation_data = ([valid_img, valid_padded_txt, valid_input_length, 
                              valid_label_length], [np.zeros(len(valid_img))]), 
          verbose = 1, callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

> Train on 25000 samples, validate on 15000 samples

```
Epoch 1/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 159s 6ms/step - loss: 13.6510 - acc: 0.0199 - val_loss: 11.4910 - val_acc: 0.0651

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 11.49100, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 2/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 146s 6ms/step - loss: 10.9559 - acc: 0.0603 - val_loss: 9.7359 - val_acc: 0.0904

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 11.49100 to 9.73587, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 3/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 146s 6ms/step - loss: 9.0720 - acc: 0.0943 - val_loss: 7.3571 - val_acc: 0.1565

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 9.73587 to 7.35715, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 4/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 145s 6ms/step - loss: 6.9501 - acc: 0.1520 - val_loss: 5.5228 - val_acc: 0.2303

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 7.35715 to 5.52277, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 5/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 144s 6ms/step - loss: 5.4893 - acc: 0.2129 - val_loss: 4.3179 - val_acc: 0.2895

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 5.52277 to 4.31793, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 6/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 4.7053 - acc: 0.2612 - val_loss: 3.7490 - val_acc: 0.3449

Epoch 00006: val_loss improved from 4.31793 to 3.74896, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 7/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 4.1183 - acc: 0.3096 - val_loss: 3.5902 - val_acc: 0.3805

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 3.74896 to 3.59015, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 8/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6662 - acc: 0.3462 - val_loss: 3.7923 - val_acc: 0.3350

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 3.59015
Epoch 9/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 3.3398 - acc: 0.3809 - val_loss: 3.1352 - val_acc: 0.4344

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 3.59015 to 3.13516, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 10/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 3.0199 - acc: 0.4129 - val_loss: 2.9798 - val_acc: 0.4541

Epoch 00010: val_loss improved from 3.13516 to 2.97978, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 11/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 2.7361 - acc: 0.4447 - val_loss: 3.3836 - val_acc: 0.3780

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 2.97978
Epoch 12/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 2.5127 - acc: 0.4695 - val_loss: 2.9266 - val_acc: 0.5041

Epoch 00012: val_loss improved from 2.97978 to 2.92656, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 13/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 142s 6ms/step - loss: 2.3045 - acc: 0.4974 - val_loss: 2.7329 - val_acc: 0.5174

Epoch 00013: val_loss improved from 2.92656 to 2.73294, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 14/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 141s 6ms/step - loss: 2.1245 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 2.8624 - val_acc: 0.5339

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 2.73294
Epoch 15/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 142s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9091 - acc: 0.5524 - val_loss: 2.6933 - val_acc: 0.5506

Epoch 00015: val_loss improved from 2.73294 to 2.69333, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 16/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 141s 6ms/step - loss: 1.7565 - acc: 0.5705 - val_loss: 2.7697 - val_acc: 0.5461

Epoch 00016: val_loss did not improve from 2.69333
Epoch 17/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 145s 6ms/step - loss: 1.6273 - acc: 0.5892 - val_loss: 2.8992 - val_acc: 0.5361

Epoch 00017: val_loss did not improve from 2.69333
Epoch 18/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 145s 6ms/step - loss: 1.5007 - acc: 0.6182 - val_loss: 2.9558 - val_acc: 0.5345

Epoch 00018: val_loss did not improve from 2.69333
Epoch 19/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 1.3775 - acc: 0.6311 - val_loss: 2.8437 - val_acc: 0.5744

Epoch 00019: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0019999999552965165.

Epoch 00019: val_loss did not improve from 2.69333
Epoch 20/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 144s 6ms/step - loss: 0.9636 - acc: 0.7115 - val_loss: 2.6072 - val_acc: 0.6083

Epoch 00020: val_loss improved from 2.69333 to 2.60724, saving model to best_model.hdf5
Epoch 21/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 146s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7940 - acc: 0.7583 - val_loss: 2.6613 - val_acc: 0.6167

Epoch 00021: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 22/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 146s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6995 - acc: 0.7797 - val_loss: 2.7180 - val_acc: 0.6220

Epoch 00022: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 23/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 144s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6197 - acc: 0.8046 - val_loss: 2.7504 - val_acc: 0.6226

Epoch 00023: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 24/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5668 - acc: 0.8167 - val_loss: 2.8238 - val_acc: 0.6255

Epoch 00024: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0003999999724328518.

Epoch 00024: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 25/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 144s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5136 - acc: 0.8316 - val_loss: 2.8167 - val_acc: 0.6283

Epoch 00025: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 26/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5012 - acc: 0.8370 - val_loss: 2.8244 - val_acc: 0.6299

Epoch 00026: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 27/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4886 - acc: 0.8425 - val_loss: 2.8366 - val_acc: 0.6282

Epoch 00027: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 28/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 143s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4820 - acc: 0.8432 - val_loss: 2.8447 - val_acc: 0.6271

Epoch 00028: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0001.

Epoch 00028: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 29/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 141s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4643 - acc: 0.8452 - val_loss: 2.8538 - val_acc: 0.6278

Epoch 00029: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
Epoch 30/30
25000/25000 [==============================] - 141s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4576 - acc: 0.8496 - val_loss: 2.8555 - val_acc: 0.6277

Epoch 00030: val_loss did not improve from 2.60724
```

> Evaluation of the model

```
test_history = model.evaluate([test_img, test_padded_txt, 
                   test_input_length, test_label_length], 
                   y=np.zeros(len(test_img)), verbose = 1)
test_history
```

> Output

```
13830/13830 [==============================] - 42s 3ms/step
[2.855567638786134, 0.6288503253882292]
```

[image: Training and Validation Accuracy]

[image: Training and Validation Loss]

> Some Predicted Output:
>   [image: Predictions]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have already tried, but did you check if your training and validation samples are balanced? That is, whether they have roughly the same percentages of examples in each category.

You could shuffle 'samples' using 'random.shuffle(samples)' before executing your following code:

`splitIdx = int(0.75 * len(samples))
train_samples = samples[:splitIdx]`

That way, you can be more certain that your training and validation sets are balanced.

Comment: Thank you for giving your time for my problem. I will definitely try that

Comment: I have modified the code but I'm still facing the similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you can do.

- Add batch normalization after every conv2d layer
- Replace maxpooling with conv2d valid padding so it becomes a learnable layer

from: `pool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(conv_1)`

to: `pool_1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=2, padding='valid')(conv_1)`

- Add l2 [regularization](https://keras.io/regularizers/) to your layers, look [here](https://keras.io/regularizers/) for implementation
- Try [weight decay](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-overfitting-in-deep-learning-with-weight-regularization/)
- Increase the dropout values you already have
- Modify your learning rate, too small and it might fall into a local minimum

And here is a lot more, the only way to know is to try them out

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner, I do not get what do you mean by "Replace maxpooling with conv2d valid padding so it becomes a learnable layer"... is it just adding padding = 'valid' in conv2d layer?

Comment: updated, you can look at `applications.resnet50.ResNet50` for another example

Comment: Sorry, would you please show me how to add I2 regularization to my CTC loss function.

Comment: I added a link to show how to add it to your layers, it's kernel_regularize parameter

Comment: I understood how to add it to the layers, but still I have not understood on how to apply regularization on my CTC loss function. Would you please elaborate on the loss function.

Comment: adding it to the layers is what i meant, I don't think keras has a good way of doing it to the loss function

Comment: I have added learnable layers replacing first two of the pooling layers, then added batch Normalization after every conv2d layers and added regularizer on LSTM and Dense layers. But the loss is very large and it stops decreasing after some epocs.

Comment: When your loss stops going down your model has converged, you can add/remove layers or increase nodes/decrease nodes in a layer

Comment: I have tried going decreasing the layers and nodes but still got the same problem.